# WCF 504 Error - Response Disappears - ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.Server returned 0 bytes

Tags: c#, wcf, http, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have WPF client which is talking to a WCF Service. On sending big request from the wpf client to WCF service, i am not getting back with the response from WCF sometimes. I am getting Null as response. Its look like data is being disappear on the wire and not sure about that. I have tried to enable WCF tracing and there is no exception in it :( Not sure what went wrong. I have increased the timeout in IIS to 900 seconds. But  no luck. I have increased the buffer size in bindings and all possible web.config settings and no luck. Any one can help me on this issue.

P.S: Our Service Hosted on IIS 7.5 Web Server.

Thaks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: I have found the issue. The issue with F5 TCP Timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation, i have found the problem. Issue with TCP Timeout in F5 url. After increasing the timeout it works fine.